# create a data.frame from an existing one - R

Tags: r

I have 2 dataframes:

```
df1=data.frame(stock=c("a","b","a","b"), year=(1999,2000,2000,1999), RetNet=c(23%,45%,56%,82%))

df2=data.frame(stock=c("a","a","[b][1]","b"), year=(1999,2000,1999,2000), RetGr=(67%,10%,54%,88%))
```

how do I create a new df with the columns "Stock","Year","RetNet" and "RetGr" by matching "Stock" and "Year"?

output desired: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNoKc.png

Comment: What output do you precisely want?

Comment: Hi, from what you described, we are not able to know if you wish to find just the rows which there are a match in the both two original dfs... 

if so, you can get it using inner_join (dplyr)

    library(dplyr)
    df3<-inner_join(df1,df2,by=c("stock","year"))

but, depending on what you need, you can also use left_join, right_join or full_join...

look here https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html

Comment: Maybe - df1 <- df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, 
            by = c("stock" = "stock")). Also why would you use = in R code.

Comment: I have added the link of a picture of the output. I tried left_join but it allows the match on the base of only one column why i need to use two matching columns: stock and year, a combination of the two

Comment: you need to include the two columns because you have two stocks "a", one with year "2000", another "1999"... by=c("stock","year") should work... as your columns has the same name... otherwise, the alternative is by=c("stock"="stock","year"="year"). But if "[b][1]" need to be considered the same of "b", you need to treat it as proposed by @Chris-Ruehlemann below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First streamline values in `stock` to one another by replacing `[b][1]`by `b`; then use `merge`on `stock`and `year`:

```
df2$stock <- sub("\\[b]\\[1]", "b", df2$stock)
merge(df1, df2, by = c("stock", "year"))
  stock year RetNet RetGr
1     a 1999    23%   67%
2     a 2000    56%   10%
3     b 1999    82%   54%
4     b 2000    45%   88%
```

Data:

```
df1=data.frame(stock=c("a","b","a","b"), year=c(1999,2000,2000,1999), RetNet=c("23%","45%","56%","82%"))

df2=data.frame(stock=c("a","a","[b][1]","b"), year=c(1999,2000,1999,2000), RetGr=c("67%","10%","54%","88%"))
```